# how to let wcf service to accept only 1 client each time

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a question about WCF service which give the client the ability to mess up with Computer files (copy/paste/delete...etc).
 service should accept only 1 client at a time, it shouldn't accept a client while another client is already connected, so what configuration does this job?
I'm using NetTcpBinding.

Comment: Service contract can consist of several methods. Host can create service instances in different ways. So, what is "client connected"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentcalls.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need not to do anything as default service behavior is to execute one call at a time. Which means if A is invoking X method and B also want to invoke X method then B request wont be entertain till A request is finished.

But if your are thinking that even after method execution nobody should access the methods then you have to handle this at your own by using Sessions!!

Comment: the client searchs for online service ,it should show a list of service and its status[Available/Busy], It's the kind of application like PcAnyWhere if you had heard about it, like when a client is already connected, the other client should got a busy status when it find that service and it will not be able to connect till the connected client is out and the service status is available, but im still new to WCF i can't figure out how to add an extra attribute to the service "status" that appears on a client search, so at this time i will just forbid a more than 1 "Session".